# DATEDIFF SQL Server 2016 JSON

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Currently have a startDate and EndDate formatted in JSON and trying to use a DATEDIFF function to work out the year difference using OPENJSON.

I am currently trying the below

```
DECLARE @Json VARCHAR(4000) = '
{
  "Name": "bob",
  "StartDate": "12/02/2015",
  "EndDate": "12/02/2016"
}';



SELECT  Name ,
        StartDate ,
        EndDate
FROM    OPENJSON(@Json, '$')
WITH (Name VARCHAR(50), StartDate DATETIME2, EndDate DATETIME2
,DATEDIFF(YEAR, StartDate DATETIME2, EndDate DATETIME2) INT AS Duration
)
WHERE Name = 'bob'
```

However, I get error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.

Anyone know if it is possible to do what I am doing?  Or propose another way?  I'd like to avoid creating a temp table, inserting into it and then reading from it with the DATEDIFF on the select if possible.

Comment: You could use a derived table, aka a subquery with an alias.

Comment: what is bob's last name?

Comment: @Robert Stanley - Wiley.  Bobs surname is Wiley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used `OPENJSON`, but shouldn't the `WITH` section contain the definition of the `Duration` column as opposed to the `DATEDIFF` and then move the `DATEDIFF` to the `SELECT`. Like so:

```
DECLARE @Json VARCHAR(4000) = '
{
  "Name": "bob",
  "StartDate": "12/02/2015",
  "EndDate": "12/02/2016"
}';

SELECT  Name ,
        StartDate ,
        EndDate ,
        DATEDIFF(YEAR, StartDate, EndDate) AS Duration
FROM    OPENJSON(@Json, '$')
WITH (Name VARCHAR(50), StartDate DATETIME2, EndDate DATETIME2, Duration INT
)
WHERE Name = 'bob'
```

Or just do the `DATEDIFF` in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT  Name ,
        StartDate ,
        EndDate ,
        DATEDIFF(YEAR, StartDate, EndDate) AS Duration
FROM    OPENJSON(@Json, '$')
WITH (Name VARCHAR(50), StartDate DATETIME2, EndDate DATETIME2)
WHERE Name = 'bob'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Moving the DATEDIFF to the select done the job.

When I tried this I left the date formatting in the DATEDIFF.

Comment: In the first example in answer, Duration column in WITH clause is useless. It will try to find Duration key in JSON and it will always return NULL because it does not exists. Probably you should leave just second example. Also, you don't need second parameter '$' in OPENJSON(@Json, '$') $ is default value so you can use just OPENJSON(@Json)

Comment: @JocaPC Thanks for pointing that out on the default value on the OPENJSON.  Think I left this in from the example I was actually using rather than the quick mock up I made.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of following solutions (untested):

```
SELECT  s.*, Duration = DATEDIFF(YEAR, StartDate, EndDate)
FROM (
    SELECT  Name ,
            StartDate   = CONVERT(DATE, StartDateChar, 103),
            EndDate     = CONVERT(DATE, EndDateChar, 103)
    FROM    OPENJSON(@Json, '$') WITH (Name VARCHAR(50), StartDateChar VARCHAR(10), EndDateChar VARCHAR(10))
    WHERE   Name = 'bob'
) AS s
```

or

```
SELECT  *, Duration = DATEDIFF(YEAR, StartDate, EndDate)
FROM    OPENJSON(@Json, '$') WITH (Name VARCHAR(50), StartDateChar VARCHAR(10), EndDateChar VARCHAR(10))
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT          
        StartDate   = CONVERT(DATE, StartDateChar, 103),
        EndDate     = CONVERT(DATE, EndDateChar, 103)
) x
WHERE   Name = 'bob'
```